# Сортировка по двум таблицам базы

Tags: mysql, php, запрос-в-запросе, запрос

Есть 2 таблицы post, comments:

```
tasks: id,title,created
task_logs: id,tasks_id,comment,timestamp
```

Нужно показать последние изменения в задачах (список задач от последних измененных), будь то изменения в самой задаче или добавлен комментарий в ней.

В php все это обрабатывать, я думаю, неправильно...
Родился у меня один запросик для MySql:

```
SELECT
    *,
IF(tasks.created>task_logs.`timestamp`,tasks.created,task_logs.`timestamp`) AS CheckedDate
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN task_logs ON task_logs.tid = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.oid = 1
GROUP BY tasks.id
ORDER BY CheckedDate DESC
LIMIT 0,8
```

И он даже работает, но там, где `LEFT JOIN task_logs ON task_logs.tid = tasks.id`, я не могу отсортировать, чтоб выбрать последнюю запись.

Возможно заставить LEFT JOIN выбрать последнюю запись или как написать выборку правильно?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сам написал костыль:

```
SELECT
    tasks.*,
    tskLog.`timestamp`,
    IF(tasks.created>tskLog.`timestamp`,tasks.created,tskLog.`timestamp`) AS CheckedDate
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM task_logs ORDER BY task_logs.`timestamp` DESC) as tskLog ON tskLog.tid = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.oid = 1
GROUP BY tasks.id
ORDER BY CheckedDate DESC
LIMIT 0,8
```

Может, кому надо будет!